# How to add a username to Firebase database upon registration?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Upon logging in I want my app to make a new field in the Firebase database with the child named after the username.

```
    if let email = emailField.text, let pass = passwordField.text {

        // Check if it's sign in or register
        if isLogin {
            // Sign in the user with Firebase
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) in

                // Check that user isn't nil
                if let u = user {
                    // User is found, go to home screen

                    self.ref?.child(email).childByAutoId().setValue("1")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goHome", sender: self)
                    print("yes")
                }
```

When I try to do this, it gives me an error called `SIGABART` which I believe is associated with not having segues connected properly.

Yet if I delete this line: 
    self.ref?.child(email).childByAutoId().setValue("1")

or change the `email` field to a random string like `"test"`, it works fine and appears in Firebase.

Comment: A `FIRUser` has a `displayName` property that you can update with a `FIRUserProfileChangeRequest` if you are just trying to associate a name with a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you can't use symbol `@` in nodes names. It's first problem. You can do it another, I think better, way:

You need to create user to ref like:

```
/users/uid from created FIRUser.
```

You can do it with next steps:

For example, your registration page will have 3 `UITextFields`: `userEmail`, `userLogin` and `userPassword`.

```
// *1* Create user
FIRAuth.auth()!.createUser(withEmail: userEmail.text!,
                             password: userPassword.text!)
  { user, error in
     if error == nil {
        // *2* Then log him in
        FIRAuth.auth()!.signIn(withEmail: self.userEmail.text!,
                               password: self.userPassword.text!)
        { result in
           // *3* Create new user in database, not in FIRAuth
           let uid = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!
           let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "someStartPart/users").child(uid)
           ref.setValue(["uid": uid, "email": userEmail.text!, "login": userLogin.text!, "creationDate": String(describing: Date())])

           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromRegistrationToMainPage", sender: self)
        }
     } else {
        print("\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
     }
  }
```

Like this. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth will not allow you to store such a value. You will need to save this into Firebase Database or another service. e.g. In the Firebase Database:

```
userRef.setValue("username123")
```

Comment: yes I have FirebaseDatabase imported in my project as well. I tried making a separate string variable, assigning the email string to that then sending it to firebase but it still gives me the SIGABRT error. The problem seems to be with the email field, even if I convert it to a string or assign it to a variable the problem persists. Wouldn't assigning it to a stirng fix the auth problem? That's what's confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the username value in the database. Something like this:

```
FIRdatabase.database().reference().child("yourchildname").updateChild(u)
```

(Im on my phone, so the call might not be EXACTLY like that, but should be very close)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

```
        //***** for realTime database
        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://add your project URL")
        let userRef = ref.child("users").child(user.user.uid)
        let values = ["Email": email, "UserName": userName] //userName is the name of textField
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value